# Ruby program for searching words in a file

Tags: ruby, argv

I started with Ruby yesterday, I only have some experience with C.
Now I'm trying to write a program that gets a file and a word to search in that file from ARGV, and prints how many times the word appeared. Got rid of any error, but it prints 0 anyway when I test it.

```
if ARGV.size !=2
        puts "INSERT A FILE AND A WORD OR A CHAR TO SEARCH FOR"
        exit 1
else
        file = File.open(ARGV[0], mode = "r")
        word = ARGV[1]
        if !file
                puts "ERROR: INVALID INPUT FILE"
                exit 1
        end
        while true
                begin
                i = 0
                count_word = 0
                string = []
                string[i] = file.readline
                if string[i].upcase.include? word.upcase
                        count_word += 1
                end
                i += 1
                rescue EOFError
                break
                end
        end
        print "The word searched is  ", word, "  Frequency: ", count_word, "\n"
end
```

I hope you could tell me what's wrong (I believe I do something wrong when counting), thanks in advance.

Comment: You can (must, actually) insert code in the body of the question, instead of a link to some 3rd party. Links tend to become broken and sometimes they're not safe to click.

Answer (score 1):

A great thing about Ruby it that it operates on a way higher level of abstraction. Here is a snippet that does what you want:

```
if ARGV.size != 2
  puts "Provide file to be searched in and word to be found"
  exit 1
end

file = ARGV[0]
word = ARGV[1]

count = 0
File.open(file, 'r').each { |line| count += 1 if line.downcase.include? word.downcase }

puts "The word searched is #{word}  Frequency: #{count}"
```

As you can see, the language provides a lot of features like string interpolation, enumeration of the file contents, etc.

There is a handful of problems with the code you provided. From styling issues like indentation, to incorrect assumptions about the language like the `if !file` check and strange decisions overall - like why do you use a list if you want only the current line.

I suggest you to look at http://tryruby.org/ . It is very short and will get you a feel of the Ruby way to do things. Also it covers your question (processing files).

As a general note when you post a question on stackoverflow, please include the code in the question, rather than link to an external page. This way people can read through it faster, edit it and the code wont be lost if the other site goes down. You can still link to external pages if you want to show the snippet in action.

Comment: Great, I'll include the code next time. Anyway I'd like to see the correct code, but still in the style I wrote it (very C-like style). I don't wanna go too deep with Ruby at the moment, I just want to use it for a better understanding of the logic of the program itself, more than the language. I will see all the other stuff after passing my C exam (which happens to be on monday), for now I want to maintain a higher level of abstraction than C, but not that high (for now at least).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you, the error that you did is that you included this part:

```
  i = 0
  count_word = 0
  string = []
```

into the `while` loop, which every time resets your counter to zero even if it found the word, so to correct this error here what you should do:

```
if ARGV.size !=2
  puts "INSERT A FILE AND A WORD OR A CHAR TO SEARCH FOR"
  exit 1
else
  file = File.open(ARGV[0], mode = "r")
  word = ARGV[1]
  if !file
    puts "ERROR: INVALID INPUT FILE"
    exit 1
  end
  i = 0
  count_word = 0
  string = []
  while true
    begin

      string[i] = file.readline
      if string[i].upcase.include? word.upcase
        count_word += 1
      end
      i += 1
    rescue EOFError
      break
    end
  end
  print "The word searched is  ", word, "  Frequency: ", count_word, "\n"
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I wanted! stupid mistake, I initialized the variables in the loop so they reset every time the loop starts. Thanks again!